# How to change bash version with homebrew

Tags: macos, bash

I have used homebrew to install the newest version of bash on my local system. I have added a symbolic link from: `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.20/bin/bash` and added the line: `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells`

When I load my terminal I am still getting the older version of bash, also when i execute the command: `/etc/local/Cellar/bash/4.2.20/bin/bash` my prompt changes to `bash-4.2$` but when i do `bash --version` it still says I am in version 3.2. Does anyone know what step I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to change your account's login shell from System Preferences, Users & Groups. You need to access the Advanced Options by right-clicking on your username and changing your shell to `/usr/local/bin/bash`. Once you've done that, restart Terminal.app (to make sure no old sessions with the wrong shell are left hanging around) and you should be set.

[image: Change login shell]

You can do the same using `dscl`:

```
dscl . -change /Users/<username> UserShell /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Comment: Are you sure about the logging out part? I've always found that simply restarting Terminal.app is enough. But I don't remember if I had to log out for Lion.

Comment: Good point - it's probably not necessary (restarting Terminal.app should suffice). I'll adjust my answer - thanks.

Comment: Interesting, I already have this line this set. But the bash version is still 3.2.

Comment: @trev9065 Are you sure it's not because of your $PATH? Can you do an "echo $BASH_VERSION" after opening Terminal.app and let us know the results?

Comment: @mjturner ok so when i did  `echo $BASH_VERSION` it gave me 4.2, why is the bash variable set but not the path. Should I set the path to my `/usr/local/bin/bash` or is it not necessary?

Comment: @trev9065 It seems like your $PATH has /usr/bin before /usr/local/bin, so when you run "bash --version", /usr/bin/bash (ie 3.2) is run, and not /usr/local/bin/bash (4.2). Solution is to re-order your $PATH (in .bashrc or .bash_profile for example). Your shell is definitely 4.2 though (as evidenced by the result of the "echo $BASH_VERSION").

Comment: Thanks for this. Helped me out a lot. @trev9065 you should accept this answer and grant the rep he earned.